# Is there a way to access the target bean from within a Bean Validation field-level ConstraintValidator?

Tags: java, validation, bean-validation, nhibernate-validator

Apart from using class-level validations, is there a way to access the parent bean of a field-level validation annotation from within its validator class?

For example:

```
public class CustomValidator implements ConstraintValidator<CustomValidation, String> {

    @Override
    public void initialize(final CustomValidation constraintAnnotation) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(final String fieldValue, final ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        // is there a way to access the parent object here?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upon further investigation, it turns out this is not possible with the version 1.1 of the spec.