# How to get the value of associate field using reflection

Tags: java, reflection

```
class A {

     private String someField;

     @validation
     private String annotatedField;
}
```

I'm implementing a custom constraint validation annotation `@validation` to validate `annotatedField`. I need to know the value of `someField` to satisfy the logic of my validation.

```
Validator implements ConstraintValidator<validation, String>{

      @Override
      public void initialize(validation constraintAnnotation) {

      }

      @Override
      public boolean isValid(String annotatedField, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {

           if (StringUtils.isBlank(annotatedField)) {
                return true;
           }

           String someField; // get some someField value given the annotatedField

      }
}
```

Is there a way to do this using reflection?

Comment: Given an object, you can reflectively determine the value of a field.  There are plenty of existing resources on how to do that.  Or is your question about something else?

Comment: Yes it's pretty easy to know the value of `someField` using reflection; what have you tried so far, and what went wrong?
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the fields in an Object via reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989560/how-to-get-the-fields-in-an-object-via-reflection)

Comment: updated my question.

Comment: This problem is not a good candidate for solving via annotations.

Comment: You'd better approach this with a class-level constraint as previously referred by https://stackoverflow.com/a/2783859/1654233, for example.

Comment: @yegodm Yes class-level constraint would be the easy solution to this. but to my case, `@validation` annotation is dedicated only for field `annotatedField`. for me, it doesnt make sense to make `@validation` annotation a class-level for a workaround. thanks

Comment: @tddiaz I'm afraid class-level constraint is not a easy solution or a workaround, but **the** solution provided by `javax.validation` design. There is no feature in the framework that would let you access the object owning a property when your validator target is a property. Please, also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/27007233/1654233.

Comment: Note that you should really rename `validation` to `Validation`, per overwhelming Java convention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This turns out to be not possible.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27007233/is-there-a-way-to-access-the-target-bean-from-within-a-bean-validation-field-lev)

A class-level constraint annotation would be recommended to address this problem.